Inference of Finetuned LLama3 using Lora Adapter - Slow and not using GPU
I finetuned the LLama3-8B-Instruct model while using a Lora Adapter.
To evaluated the model, I would like to perform sequential inference but it is extremely slow and does not use GPU (22 seconds per sample).
How can I improve the inference time by using GPU or using batch inference?
Here is my current python inference pipeline:
base_model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    base_model_id,
    return_dict=True,
    torch_dtype=torch.float16,
)

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(base_model_id)
chat_template = open('llama-3-instruct.jinja').read()
chat_template = chat_template.replace('    ', '').replace('\n', '')
tokenizer.chat_template = chat_template

# Merge base model with the adapter
model = PeftModel.from_pretrained(base_model, new_model_id)
model = model.merge_and_unload()

# Save model and tokenizer
model.save_pretrained(new_model_id)
tokenizer.save_pretrained(new_model_id)

# Create pipeline
pipeline = transformers.pipeline(
    "text-generation",
    model=new_model_id,
    tokenizer=tokenizer
)

def classification_pipeline(netflow):

    message = [
        {"role": "system", "content": instruction_prompt},
        {"role": "user", "content": netflow},
    ]

    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(new_model_id)
    prompt = tokenizer.apply_chat_template(message, add_generation_prompt=True, tokenize=False)

    # Generate text
    outputs = pipeline(
        prompt,
        do_sample=True,
        temperature=0.01,
        top_p=0.9,
        num_return_sequences=1,
        max_new_tokens=100,
        pad_token_id = 50256
    )

    return outputs[0]["generated_text"][len(prompt):]

prediction_labels = []
for i in dataset:
    prediction_labels.append(classification_pipeline(i['input']))

